# Determine if a class is a field on another class

Tags: java, class, object

I have a java class that looks like this:

```
public class MainClass {

  public static class InnerClass1 extends SomeClass {
    ...
  }

  public static class InnerClass2 extends SomeClass {
    ...
  }
}
```

At runtime, is there a way examine an object that's an instance of InnerClass1 and know that its a field on MainClass?  I know I can add a static array to MainClass that contains a list of its SomeClass fields, but I'd like something that's a bit more programmatically dynamic.  Something like this:

```
MainClass.InnerClass1 object1 = someKindOfFactory.getObject();
BigDecimal someNumber = new BigDecimal("45.77");

if (object1.comesFrom(MainClass.class)) {
  LOG.debug("Object is from MainClass");
} else {
  LOG.debug("Object comes from somewhere else");
}

if (someNumber.comesFrom(MainClass.class)) {
  LOG.debug("Object is from MainClass");
} else {
  LOG.debug("Object comes from somewhere else");
}
```

Results:

```
DEBUG: Object is from MainClass
DEBUG: Object comes from somewhere else
```

Comment: You're asking for doing things backwards. You need to iterate over the `Field` instances of `MainClass` and check if their type is `InnerClass1`.

Comment: A class isn't a field - so your question is confusing. What *exactly* do you mean?

Comment: Pass a reference of parent instance to inner fields - do not confuse classes and instances.

Comment: I still don't understand what your logic for `comesFrom` is. An object cannot know where it was created. Are you asking if the type of the object is an inner type of `MainClass`?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell exactly what you're trying to achieve but `Class.getEnclosingClass()` may help you here:

```
MainClass.InnerClass1 object1 = someKindOfFactory.getObject();
BigDecimal someNumber = new BigDecimal("45.77");

if (object1.getClass().getEnclosingClass() == MainClass.class) {
  LOG.debug("Object is from MainClass");
} else {
  LOG.debug("Object comes from somewhere else");
}

if (someNumber.getClass().getEnclosingClass() == MainClass.class) {
  LOG.debug("Object is from MainClass");
} else {
  LOG.debug("Object comes from somewhere else");
}
```

In this case `object1.getClass().getEnclosingClass() == MainClass.class` is true if `object1` is an instance of `InnerClass1` directly, but *false* if `object1` is a subclass of `InnerClass1` that is declared somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

When you create an object and hold a reference to it

```
Object obj = new Object();
```

you can pass around this reference pretty much anywhere you want, ie. assign it to a class field, use it as a method argument, etc. There's nothing linking it to a specific class field.

Similarly, an inner class has a reference to its outer class. However, you can have any number of inner class objects created. The outer class has no way of knowing how many or which they are (imagine the garbage collection nightmare).

Answer (score 0):

If what you mean is to determine, at runtime, whether a given field is defined in the subclass or the superclass, you'd have to use getDeclaredFields on the Class object of the subclass and see if the field in question is listed.  Of course, you  first need to get the field name, and it's not obvious how you do that.